# Audio analysis in iOS for beginners

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, audio-streaming, audio-analysis

I'd like to start developing some iOS apps involving audio analysis. I've been reading some Apple's documentation such as [Audio Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), but I still need a starting point to audio analysis. I would like to know how could I do things like, for example, in `Shazam` app: how could you "compare" two audio files/streams? Or like several other apps do: how could you detect the rhythm of an audio file or stream to show, let's say, an animation moving at the same rhythm?

I need some guidence, I know I'm missing some audio analysis basics and I'd appreciate some starting point to learn them and how to apply them in iOS apps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For Shazam-type matching, google MFCCs and audio fingerprinting.  For beat detection, check the MIREX/music-ir web site for research papers on audio beat tracking.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the following github?

https://github.com/TheAmazingAudioEngine/TheAmazingAudioEngine

also the following website:

http://www.synthtopia.com/content/2015/01/12/audiokit-an-open-source-platform-for-audio-synthesis-processing-and-analysis/